# Suppress warning give in ps command output

Tags: linux, ps

When I run the ps command i get a warning saying "Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.7/FAQ"

How do i suppress this warning? Is there some system setting that i must do for this. The command that i fire is :

```
[root@localhost home]# ps -aux | grep "curl -s -o Test" 

Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.7/FAQ
root      4856  0.0  0.0   4044   672 pts/0    S+   07:20   0:00 grep curl -s -o Test
[root@localhost home]#
```

Note that I have to fire the exact same command as above. That is why i am looking for some system setting that will suppress the warning.

Comment: Just to be clear: You cannot remove the "-" and turn it into "ps aux", right?

Comment: Yes, I cannot do that. I have to fire the exact same command as given above.

Comment: Just remove the '-' before aux will solve

Answer (score 2):

From the FAQ:

> Why does "ps -aux" complain about a bogus '-'?
>
> According to the POSIX and UNIX standards, the above command asks to display
> all processes with a TTY (generally the commands users are running) plus all
> processes owned by a user named "x". If that user doesn't exist, then ps will
> assume you really meant "ps aux". The warning is given to gently break you of a
> habit that will cause you trouble if a user named "x" were created.

On my system, where a user `x` does not exist, I get no warning message.  Therefore one can surmise that, on your system, a user named `x` exists.

If you can remove user `x` you can probably get the warning to go away. If not, you are stuck with the warning message.

Comment: I checked the /etc/passwd file. I do not have a user with username x on my system.

Comment: My system has procps-3.2.8... maybe the behavior is slightly different with the newer version.

Comment: I was using `-f` (full format) and on RHEL6 it was complaining about a bogus `-`, which since it doesn't complain on RHEL7, would appear to be a bogus bogus `-` warning.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 ps -aux | grep "curl -s -o Test" 2> /dev/null
```

Or a variant of that.

Comment: I cannot change the command that I am firing. i.e. I cannot append anything to it.

Comment: You should ask on one of the Linux stack exchanges, you'll get better help.  Except everyone will yell at you for running as root. (:

Comment: That sends the `STDERR` (2) of `grep` to `/dev/null`, not the `STDERR` of `ps`. But anyway, you shouldn't promote grepitis: `ps -fC curl` will do the job. Man, `man man`, man. And yes, @Tim every sysadmin will yell at every developer for running unprivileged code as a privileged user. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege

Comment: @Rich I'm well aware of the PLP, hence my comment about running things as root. Also, regarding "promoting grepitis", I wasn't.  OP said that he couldn't modify the command that was run, which had already contained the grep.  I was merely trying to help him get around it with a redirect.